# Redirect domain using TLS of pointed domain

Tags: redirect, ssl, heroku

I have an app on Heroku, `app.herokuapp.com`. It uses the TLS certificate provided by Heroku, so one can query `https://app.herokuapp.com:443`.

Then I have another domain, `mydomain.com`. My question is: can I use the latter to redirect requests to the Heroku domain using TLS?

As in: could I query `https://mydomain.com:443` equivalently to `https://app.herokuapp.com:443`, and keep using Heroku's TLS certificate? Maybe some trick with Nginx? I'm not very familiar with CNAME and these things so thanks for any explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to dig a little to find the answer, which is: no, each subdomain needs its own SSL certificate, different from the Heroku base one. It also needs the 'SSL Endopoint' on Heroku (currently 20$/mo).